# get line number for XElement here

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(file);
IEnumerable<XElement> categories = xdoc.Descendants("Category");
foreach (XElement category in categories)
{
    //get line number for element here...
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(file, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
IEnumerable<XElement> categories = xdoc.Descendants("Category");
foreach (XElement category in categories)
{
    //get line number for element here...
    string lineNumber = ((IXmlLineInfo)category).HasLineInfo() ? ((IXmlLineInfo)category).LineNumber : -1;
}
```

Comment: IXmlLineInfo.LineNumber returns `int` not `string`

Comment: Personally, from C# 6, I would write it as`int lineNo = (category as IXmlLineInfo)?.LineNumber ?? -1;`

Comment: Is it possible to get the line number where the tag ends.?

Answer (score 78):

`XElement` (actually `XObject`) implements the `IXmlLineInfo` interface, so you can use it:

```
IXmlLineInfo info = category;
int lineNumber = info.LineNumber;
```

Note that line information is not always available, you need to call the `HasLineInfo` method to check if the information is available. You can specify `LoadOptions.SetLineInfo` when you load the document with `XDocument.Load`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `LoadOptions.SetLineInfo` method.

Comment: Kudos for the mention of `LoadOptions.SetLineInfo`. That was tripping me up for a bit.