# C#: Line information when parsing XML with XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

What are my options for parsing an XML file with XmlDocument and still retain line information for error messages later on? (as an aside, is it possible to do the same thing with XML Deserialisation?)

Options seem to include:

- [Extending the DOM and using IXmlLineInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e3x60fe9)
- [Using XPathDocument](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/xmlandnetfx/thread/45b9e39c-e195-4706-97ed-75f341360e85)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only other option I know of is `XDocument.Load()`, whose overloads accept `LoadOptions.SetLineInfo`. This would be consumed in much the same way as an `XmlDocument`.

[Example](https://web.archive.org/web/20160217123516/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/09/26/linq-farm-linq-to-xml-and-line-numbers.aspx)

Comment: For current .net this would be great.. but unfortunately I'm still writing for .net 2.0 from the 80s.  (I would have mentioned in the question but I didn't want to date the post)

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Between the other two, I think I would prefer the `XPathDocument` approach.

Comment: @Andy this should be an answer.. it works well if you're stuck with old C#.

Answer (score 7):

(Expanding answer from @Andy's comment)

There is no built in way to do this using `XmlDocument` (if you are using `XDocument`, you can use the [`XDocument.Load()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538371(v=vs.110).aspx) overload which accepts [`LoadOptions.SetLineInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.loadoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471001/get-line-number-for-xelement-here)).

While there's no built-in way, you can use the `PositionXmlDocument` wrapper class from here (from the [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx) project):

https://github.com/icsharpcode/WpfDesigner/blob/5a994b0ff55b9e8f5c41c4573a4e970406ed2fcd/WpfDesign.XamlDom/Project/PositionXmlDocument.cs

In order to use it, you will need to use the `Load` overload that accepts an `XmlReader` (the other `Load` overloads will go to the regular `XmlDocument` class, which will not give you line number information). If you are currently using the `XmlDocument.Load` overload that accepts a filename, you will need to change your code as follows:

```
using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(filename))
{
    var doc = new PositionXmlDocument();
    doc.Load(reader);
}
```

Now, you should be able to cast any `XmlNode` from this document to a `PositionXmlElement` to retrieve line number and column:

```
var node = doc.ChildNodes[1];
var elem = (PositionXmlElement) node;
Console.WriteLine("Line: {0}, Position: {1}", elem.LineNumber, elem.LinePosition);
```

Comment: This is really good for adding retrospectivley - I had written lots of code based on XmlDocument, and simply by adding this file and then adding the 3 lines of code suggested I am able to have useful positional user feedback : ) ... you need to add `using ICSharpCode.WpfDesign.XamlDom;` - that's probably blindingly obvious to C# users, but I am new to C# :o  ... +1!