# Is it possible to get line numbers/positions from a System.Xml.XmlNode when working with a System.Xml.XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-3.5, xmlnode

The title says it all...

Is it possible to get line numbers/positions from a `System.Xml.XmlNode` when working with a `System.Xml.XmlDocument`?

I want the information so that I can inform the user of where they need to look in their Xml file for specific pieces of information.  I've seen similar questions relating to an `XmlReader` on SO but nothing that actually answers my question.

I guess I could search the xml file for the `OuterXml` of the node that I'm interested in, but that seems hacky, and what if that information appears in the file more than once?  There must be a better way?

**Update:**
I'm loading my xml file using:

```
xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
xmlDoc.Load(filename);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: Line information when parsing XML with XmlDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628980/c-line-information-when-parsing-xml-with-xmldocument)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is going to help someone, but I had similar objective to the OP. In my particular case, I have an XmlDocument and I needed to have the line number of all the Textbox nodes. Since I was getting the same Exception MadSkunk described, I figured that the only was to create an XPathDocument instance and do the casting.

Richard Schneider's answer helped me to visualise that. So my current method looks like this:

```
public Dictionary<int, string> GetLineNumber()
{
    Dictionary<int, string> attrByLineNumber = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream();
    _xmlDoc.Save(xmlStream);
    xmlStream.Position = 0;
    XPathDocument pathDocument = new XPathDocument(xmlStream);
    foreach (XPathNavigator element in pathDocument.CreateNavigator().Select("//*"))
    {
        if (element.Name.Equals("Textbox"))
        {
            attrByLineNumber.Add(((IXmlLineInfo)element).LineNumber, element.GetAttribute("Name", ""));
        }
    }
    return attrByLineNumber;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using the [IXmlLineInfo interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.xml.ixmllineinfo.aspx).

I know that with `XDocument` and `XPathDocument` you can just cast a node to `IXmlLineInfo`.  I think its also possible with XmlDocument.

Comment: Nope, can't use it with an XmlDocument

Comment: `IXmlLineInfo` only helps if the information was set by the underlying `XmlReader`.

Comment: As John suggested, you need your `XmlReader` to set line info.  Could you post how you reading the XmlDocument.

Comment: I've updated my question: I'm not using an XmlReader.

Comment: Load is sugar for using a XmlReader.  Its equivalent to `Load(new XmlTextReader(filename)`.  So your in-memory xml document should have the info.  Just cast the element/node to `IXmlLineInfo`.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried that.  I get `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.XmlElement' to type 'System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo'`...

Comment: @MadSkunk, did you ever passed this issue? If so, how? I'm exactly at this point of your comment.