# validating an xml and finding line and column of error

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

i have an xml document of this kind

```
   <xml>
    <person name="a">
      <age>21</age>
      <salary>50000></salary>
    </person>
    <person name="b">
      <age>25</age>
      <salary>30000></salary>
    </person>
    <person name="c">
      <age>30</age>
      <salary>60000></salary>
    </person>
    <person name="d">
      <age>35</age>
      <salary>150000></salary>
    </person>
   </xml>
```

Now im trying to validate this document by passing this to a method like this

```
  validate(string file)
  {
    // here i have some logic 
    // say i am trying to check if the salary is >50000  and age > 30
    // if it doesn't satisfy the condition i have to return an error

  }
```

I am able to achieve this . What i really want is to know where exactly the error in xml document is , like which line and column.

How should i do this ? any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [get line number for XElement here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471001/get-line-number-for-xelement-here)

Answer (score 1):

You are closing your 'age' tag like this

```
 <age>35<age/>
```

It should be like

```
<age>35</age>
```

hope this works for you.

Comment: i think this is not relevant for the question. harin04 wants to create a method which validates the xml file.

Comment: @Tobias yes , i want a method which validates and gives the line and column of error

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have not specified how you are parsing your XML in c#. It matters.

Now as for validity of your XML document, a valid xml document should have these:

- XML documents must have a root element
- XML elements must have a closing tag
- XML tags are case sensitive
- XML elements must be properly nested
  -XML attribute values must be quoted

now try adding this to the top of your xml doc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

Now, to parse XML document, you can use either `XmlDocument` class or Linq's `XDocument` class.
Lets take example of `XmlDocument`.

if you have a xml string, load Xml as below:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(stringXML);
foreach(XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("xml/person/salary"))
{
    var strSalary = node.InnerText;
    var intSalary = Convert.ToInt32(strSalary??0);
}
```

if you have a xml file, load Xml as below:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(XMLFilePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

Full example:

```
string xml = @"<xml>
<person name=""a"">
  <age>21</age>
  <salary>50000</salary>
</person>
<person name=""b"">
  <age>25</age>
  <salary>30000</salary>
</person>
<person name=""c"">
  <age>30</age>
  <salary>60000</salary>
</person>
<person name=""d"">
  <age>35</age>
  <salary>150000</salary>
</person>
</xml>";

using (var sr = new StringReader(xml))
{
    var xml2 = XDocument.Load(sr, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);

    foreach (var person in xml2.Root.Elements())
    {
        //string name = (string)person.Attribute("name"); // Unused
        int age = (int)person.Element("age");
        int salary = (int)person.Element("salary");

        // Your check
        bool error = salary > 50000 && age > 30;

        if (error)
        {
            // IMPORTANT PART HERE!!!
            int lineNumber = -1;
            int colNumber = -1;

            var lineInfo = (IXmlLineInfo)person;

            if (lineInfo.HasLineInfo())
            {
                lineNumber = lineInfo.LineNumber;
                colNumber = lineInfo.LinePosition;
            }

            return string.Format("Error on line {0}, col {1}", lineNumber, colNumber);

            // END IMPORTANT PART!!!
        }
    }
}
```

The "trick" is that `XElement` implement `IXmlLineInfo` (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471001/get-line-number-for-xelement-here)), but you have to load the document with `LoadOptions.SetLineInfo`.

Comment: So by this way , Do i have to validate each person tag separately and then find the error line?

Comment: @harin04 You are the one that wants to validate its xml file, not I. If you are asking me "is there a way to put some rules for xml files and check them", then the response is yes and no. xsd can check formally the file, something more complex can be done with  [schematron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schematron) but I don't know if there are schematron validators for .NET .

Comment: Yes i do want to validate  the xml file .But i dont want to go to every tag and check it because the my xml files are very long and not all the elements are of same type.    i want to input a xml file and find the lines where error is. Is there a way to keep track of this .

Comment: @harin04 If you want to check the file, you'll have to check all the elements you want to check. I had extracted even the `name` element that wasn't useful for the check, but you don't need to extract it. See the modified example.

Comment: @xantos okay .I try this :) thank you for yours suggestion :)