# XDocument losing line number

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm using `XDocument` to parse my XML File, but when I try to read the line number of a `XNode` or a `XElement`, it's always equal to zero.

I tried different ways to parse it:

```
foreach (XElement node in xDoc.Root.Descendants("nodeName"))
```

or

```
xDoc.XPathSelectElement("nodeName")
```

and each time `((IXmlLineInfo)node).LineNumber` returns 0!

I'm using a `XmlNamespaceManager`.

Did I miss something?

Thanks in advance!

Edit :

Here is the concerned Xml as asked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance">
<CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
<GrpHdr>
  <MsgId>XXXXXXXXX</MsgId>
  <CreDtTm>2013-06-12T00:00:00</CreDtTm>
  <NbOfTxs>1</NbOfTxs>
  <CtrlSum>136.82</CtrlSum>
  <InitgPty>
    <Nm>name</Nm>
    <Id>
      <OrgId>
        <Othr>
          <Id>XXXXXXXXX</Id>
        </Othr>
      </OrgId>
    </Id>
  </InitgPty>
</GrpHdr>
<PmtInf>
  <PmtInfId>275-20130612-FIRST</PmtInfId>
  <PmtMtd>DD</PmtMtd>      
  <BtchBookg>true</BtchBookg>
  <NbOfTxs>1</NbOfTxs>
  <CtrlSum>136.82</CtrlSum>
  <PmtTpInf>
    <SvcLvl>
      <Cd>SEPA</Cd>
    </SvcLvl>
    <LclInstrm>
      <Cd>CORE</Cd>
    </LclInstrm>
    <SeqTp>RCUR</SeqTp>
  </PmtTpInf>
  <ReqdColltnDt>2013-06-05</ReqdColltnDt>
  <Cdtr>
    <Nm>name</Nm>
    <PstlAdr>
      <Ctry>BE</Ctry>
      <AdrLine>XXXXXXXXX</AdrLine>
      <AdrLine>XXXXXXXXX</AdrLine>
    </PstlAdr>
  </Cdtr>
  <CdtrAcct>
    <Id>
      <IBAN>XXXXXXXXX</IBAN>
    </Id>
  </CdtrAcct>
  <CdtrAgt>
    <FinInstnId>
      <BIC>XXXXXXXXX</BIC>
    </FinInstnId>
  </CdtrAgt>
  <ChrgBr>SLEV</ChrgBr>
  <CdtrSchmeId>
    <Id>
      <PrvtId>
        <Othr>
          <Id>XXXXXXXXX</Id>
          <SchmeNm>
            <Prtry>SEPA</Prtry>
          </SchmeNm>
        </Othr>
      </PrvtId>
    </Id>
  </CdtrSchmeId>
  <DrctDbtTxInf>
    <PmtId>
      <InstrId>XXXXXXXXX</InstrId>
      <EndToEndId>XXXXXXXXX</EndToEndId>
    </PmtId>
    <InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">136.82</InstdAmt>
    <DrctDbtTx>
      <MndtRltdInf>
        <MndtId>XXXXXXXXX</MndtId>
        <DtOfSgntr>2009-10-31</DtOfSgntr>
        <AmdmntInd>false</AmdmntInd>
        <AmdmntInfDtls>
          <AmdmntInd>yellowland</AmdmntInd>
          <OrgnlMndtId>XXXXXXXXX</OrgnlMndtId>
          <OrgnlCdtrSchmeId>
            <Id>
              <PrvtId>
              <Othr>
                <Id>XXXXXXXXX</Id>
                <SchmeNm>
                <Prtry>SEPA</Prtry>
                </SchmeNm>
                </Othr>
              </PrvtId>
            </Id>
          </OrgnlCdtrSchmeId>
        </AmdmntInfDtls>
      </MndtRltdInf>
    </DrctDbtTx>
    <DbtrAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
            <BIC>XXXXXXXXX</BIC>
        </FinInstnId>
    </DbtrAgt>
    <Dbtr>
      <Nm>TEST</Nm>
      <PstlAdr>
        <Ctry>BE</Ctry>
        <AdrLine>XXXXXXXXX</AdrLine>
        <AdrLine>XXXXXXXXX</AdrLine>
      </PstlAdr>
    </Dbtr>
    <DbtrAcct>
      <Id>
        <IBAN>XXXXXXXXX</IBAN>
      </Id>
    </DbtrAcct>
    <RmtInf>
      <Ustrd>test</Ustrd>
    </RmtInf>
  </DrctDbtTxInf>
</PmtInf>
</CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
</Document>
```

Comment: Could you share some of your XML file

Comment: Not all XElements has lineinfo, what does a call to `HasLineInfo` yield? However, as you're parsing from file I would expect it would. Why are you casting to `IXmlLineInfo` btw, given `XElement` inherits?

Comment: `HasLineInfo` return false. WHat is the orther way to retrieve an `XElement`'s line number other than `(node as IXmlLineInfo).LineNumber` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The LineInformations are not always loaded, when you load xml via `XDocument`.

You need to specify that you also want to load the LineInformation when you load the XML. That is done by using one of the [Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods that you can pass in a value of `LoadOptions` of the `XDocument` class.

```
var document = XDocument.Load(file, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471001/get-line-number-for-xelement-here)

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(file);
IEnumerable<XElement> nodes = xdoc.Descendants("nodeName");
foreach (XElement node in nodes)
{
    IXmlLineInfo info = node;
    int lineNumber = info.LineNumber;
}
```

Comment: Thanks luliaa but that's exactly my problem. `info.LineNumber`is always zero.

Comment: @SeyoS A little bit late... but, I had the same problem. If you do like that on @Iuliia answer, it doesn't work. You need to explicitly cast the XElement item to IXmlLineInfo that way: `IXmlLineInfo info = (IXmlLineInfo)node; int lineNumber = info.HasLineInfo() ? info.LineNumber : -1;`. So it works! Also take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471001/get-line-number-for-xelement-here)