# Find XmlNode (or XPath) which corresponds to a given character index in an XML string

Tags: c#, xml, dom, xpath

I have a string `str` containing XML, which I'm able to parse into an XML DOM object by way of:

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(str);
```

Given an arbitrary character index `i`, what's the best way to find the `XmlNode` in my `XmlDocument` which corresponds to that location in the XML string? (It would be good enough to find an XPath to the deepest `XmlElement` that spans the given character position.)

My application is displaying the string `str` in a read-only text box, and I want to be able to determine where in the document the user's cursor is so I can do some magic with it.

Comment: can you show what the xml looks like.. also what do you mean when you say you want to be able to determine where in the document the user's cursor is.. please clarify what it is you're trying to do and or what you really mean..

Comment: @MethodMan The cursor is at a particular character offset in the string. The cursor corresponds to some location within the parsed XmlDocument. What is that location (what XmlNode)? Suppose the full XML string is "<a>hi</a>" and the cursor is at character offset 4. Then the cursor position corresponds to the XmlTextNode for "hi". Not sure how to make it any clearer.

Comment: [`XObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implements [`IXmlLineInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.ixmllineinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so if you switch to Linq to XML, you could use that.  See [get line number for XElement here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471001/get-line-number-for-xelement-here).

Comment: @dbc Thanks, that might be an option. Unfortunately `IXmlLineInfo` is line-and-column based, so I'd have to do some ugly string manipulation to either flatten it all to one line or generate a lookup table to convert a raw string offset into a line number / line position. I'm hoping for a cleaner solution, but yours should work in the worst case.