# How to find tag and line number in which contains special characters like @,<,>,&,*,$,# in text of xml file using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have one xml file, the content as below,

```
<Root>
   <Test> EffectiveHealthCare@ahrq.hhs.gov </Test>
</Root>
<Parent>
   <Test> Welcome</Test>
</Parent>
```

Do you know how to get tag and line no in file when contains special character?

My output looks like

**Tag** : `< Test>EffectiveHealthCare@ahrq.hhs.gov</Test>`

**Line No** : 2

**Text** :`EffectiveHealthCare@ahrq.hhs.gov`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCx48.png)

[Image2 for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471001/get-line-number-for-xelement-here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fikpO.png)

Please help me.

Thanks,

Sheena Roy

Comment: What are you using to read your XML? `File.ReadAllText(...)`, `System.Xml...` ?

Comment: Use Xdocument for loading

Comment: Please update your question with this information. Maybe give a code sample of how you're loading and working with the document.

Comment: Please sir give me any solution

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have a read of:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have tried with Xtext for text ,XElemet and i also used string for getting characters but got wrong records they given me more than and less than character of tag its incorrect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get line number for XElement here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471001/get-line-number-for-xelement-here)

Comment: I did a quick search and found a bunch of answers. Take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471001/get-line-number-for-xelement-here

Comment: Sorry sir but please try to understand my question and given explanations

Comment: yes sir i have already check this link but its not suitable for my question

Comment: Have a read of the [how to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then update your question with details of what you have tried and why it is not suitable. We can't guess at a solution to your problem without knowing what the problem is.

Comment: Hi sir,Please check above image i want that line no

Comment: please check above 2 image . i have used that link but give me this answer.I want that each and every tag give line no but in this solution not get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example (if the document is a string):

```
XDocument.Load(new StringReader(@"
<xml>
<Root>
   <Test> AnotherLine </Test>
   <Test> EffectiveHealthCare@ahrq.hhs.gov </Test>
</Root>
<Parent>
   <Test> Welcome</Test>
</Parent>
</xml>"), LoadOptions.SetLineInfo)
.Root
.Elements("Root")
.Elements("Test")
.Where(node => node.Value.IndexOfAny(new [] {'@','<','>','&','*','$','#'}) > -1 )
.Select(node => (node as IXmlLineInfo).LineNumber)
```

You need to set the `LoadOptions.SetLineInfo` input parameter when loading the document

For looking characters in any element (that is leaf node):

```
XDocument.Load(new StringReader(@"
<xml>
<Root>
   <Test> AnotherLine </Test>
   <Test> EffectiveHealthCare@ahrq.hhs.gov </Test>
</Root>
<Parent>
   <Test> Welcome</Test>
</Parent>
</xml>"), LoadOptions.SetLineInfo)
.Root
.Descendants()
.Where(node => !node.HasElements)
.Where(node => node.Value.IndexOfAny(new [] {'@','<','>','&','*','$','#'}) > -1 )
.Select(node => (node as IXmlLineInfo).LineNumber)
```

Comment: ok ill try it ...Can you tell me how to inform if special characters appeared anywhere in the text other than tags ?

Comment: Thanks sir its working.....i want one more "can possible to get tag of this line no?Please help me

Comment: mortb sir, Please reply

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question. Is this what you want: to get the the tag at a specific line?

Comment: If you want to get an element at a specific line I think you could replace the last parts of the query above with:
`.Root
.Descendants()
.Where(node => (node as IXmlLineInfo).LineNumber == <yourWantedLineNumber>)`

Comment: You're welcome :) Please upvote answer if it is possible

Comment: Sir one more please.....Is it use for &#x000AD;,&#x00AD;,&#x000A0;,&#x00A0;,&#x02010;,&#x2010;,&#x02003;,&#x2003;,&#x000B5;,&#x00B5;,&#x002DA;,&#x02DA;,&#009632;,&#09632;,&#x0FB01;,&#xFB01; ?

Comment: Can we check this entities (same as above)?

Comment: Well you can try to alter the Where call to;
`.Where(node => node.Value.IndexOfAny(new [] {'@','<','>','&','*','$','#'}) > -1 || (new [] {"&#x000AD;","&#x00AD;","&#x000A0;","&#x00A0;","&#x02010;","&#x2010;","&#x02003;","&#x2003;","&#x0‌00B5;","&#x00B5;","&#x002DA;","&#x02DA;","&#009632;","&#09632;","&#x0FB01;","&#xFB01;"}).Where(x => node.Value.Contains(x))`

Comment: Hi sir, sorry i am again and again asking you question...please sorry.. Please check this.i am asking same questions for check tag text link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504337/how-to-find-tag-and-line-number-of-specific-tag-of-xml-file-using-c-sharp........please tell me how to fixed it for same of above approch

Comment: It seems that someone has posted an answer in your other question.

Comment: HI,I have one query that i need to search with count of character (i.e '@','<','>','&','*','$','#') in a text of given tag  thourgh xdocument  In this example,count the  '@' character (eg.<contrib contrib-type="author">
  <name>
    <surname>Guthrie@.sope</surname>
    <given-names>James W.</given-names>
  </name>
  <aff>Department of Leadership, Policy and Organization, Peabody College of Vanderbil University, 230 Appleton Place, @ Nashville, TN 37203-5721, E-mail: <email xlink="jwgxiii@sbcglobal.net">jwgxiii@sbcglobal.net</email></aff>
</contrib>)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the line number you could just write:

```
var specialChars = new [] {'@','<','>','&','*','$','#'};
var linesWithSpecialChars = new List<int>();
var i = 0;
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(<yourfilename>))
{
   if(line.indexOfAny(specialChars) > -1)
   {
        linesWithSpecialChars.Add(i);
   }
   i++;
}
```

Comment: Hi ,I have load file through Xdocument ,so please give another solution