# find line number of specific tag of xml file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

How to find tag and line number of Specific tag  of xml file,
for example:

```
<sec id="fm.s2">
<title>Acknowledgments</title>
</sec>
<p>Center for Evidence and Practice Improvement</p>
<p>Agency for Healthcare Research and Quality</p>
<sec id="fm.s2">
<title>Director</title>
</sec>
<p>Center for Evidence and Practice Improvement</p>
<p>Agency for Healthcare Research and Quality</p>
<sec id="fm.s2">
<title>Acknowledgments</title>
</sec>
```

In this example, I want to get line no of which `<title>` contains "Acknowledgments" text.

Comment: Read file line by line and search for the needed text.

Comment: yes right but i want line no also of that text

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.linenumber(v=vs.110).aspx XmlTextReader class has a LineNumber property. Maybe you could find a way to use this class to get what you want. The sample code given on the page I linked looks already pretty close.

Comment: sir,i am using xdocument so i want output though xdocument so please give me another solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471001/get-line-number-for-xelement-here already answers this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with linq

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(@"path", LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);

var lineNumbers = xml.Descendants()
            .Where(x =>!x.Descendants().Any() && //exact node contains the value
                        x.Value.Contains("Acknowledgments"))
            .Cast<IXmlLineInfo>()
            .Select(x => x.LineNumber);
```

Comment: Hi sir, i want text only in <sec>/<title> tag...find text from <sec>/<title>

Comment: It is unclear what do you want. Line number or text?

Comment: I want text but which text coming in <title> tag(and hierarchy is <sec>/<title>) i want text through this hierarchy

Comment: You can do it by adding appropriate condition to where clause.

Comment: Or this :             int? lineNumber = doc.Descendants().Select((x, i) => ((x.Name.LocalName == "title") && (x.Value == "Acknowledgments")) ? (int?)i : (int?)null).Where(y => y != null).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: HI,i got solution......var varLineNos = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xDocFile.ToString()), LoadOptions.SetLineInfo)
                          .Root
                          .Descendants("sec")
                          .Where(node=> node.Element("title").Value == "Acknowledgments")
                           .Select(node => (node as IXmlLineInfo).LineNumber);

Comment: thanks to all give me your valuable time for my questions.