# How to find node with duplicate attribute values using XElement or XDocument?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Here is a small sample xml

```
<parentNode>
    <c-node>
        <myNode axs="p1">Anything goes</myNode>
        <myNode axs="p2">Nothing <aa>is</aa> here</myNode>
        <myNode axs="p1">Whatever it may be</myNode>
        <myNode axs="p3">...</myNode>
    </c-node>
</parentNode>
```

How do I find the `myNode` with duplicate attribute values `axs` and get the line number using LINQ-to-XML?

So from the above xml, the result should give the `<myNode axs="p1">` node and both of its line numbers i.e. 3 & 5 as result.

Answer (score 1):

You can get duplicated elements using group by and you can cast the `XElement` to `IXmlLineInfo` to get line number ([credits here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4471030/3010968)):

```
var nodes = document.Descendants("myNode")
            .GroupBy(node => (string)node.Attribute("axs"))
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .SelectMany(g => g.Select(node => new
            {
                Node = node,
                LineNumber = (node as IXmlLineInfo).LineNumber
            }))
            .ToList();
```

The important part is you need to pass `LoadOptions.SetLineInfo` while loading the document as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4471021/3010968) otherwise the `LineInfo` will return zero:

```
var document = XDocument.Load(path, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
```